# .on() - на одно нажатие 2 запроса

Tags: jquery, ajax

Имеется поле ввода, для живого поиска.

```
$('#ajax-input').on('keyup keypress blur change',function(event){ 
    getResult(1);
});
```

При вводе данных в поле, функция каждый раз срабатывает по два раза. Как ограничить дублирование ?

Comment: убрать keypress

Comment: если это селект, то можно оставить только `change`, разве нет?

Comment: у меня еще вставка текста дублируется

Comment: Не вижу тут никакой вставки

Comment: если в поле вставить текст, используя контекстное меню мышки, то сработает два раза тоже

Comment: В какое поле? Какое контекстное меню? Что за обработчик это обрабатывает?

Answer (score 2):

Убрать все перечисленные события, добавить одно событие `'input'`. Оно срабатывает при любом изменении значения поля. И при ручном вводе, и при вставке текста.

```
$('#ajax-input').on('input',function(event){ 
    getResult(1);
});
```

Comment: damn, а изначально там был `#ajax-select`

Comment: >> [Вызов функции не чаще, чем раз в `x` миллисекунд](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1294029/%d0%a1%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-null-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d1%91-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5#answer-1294034)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, обернуть функцию в debounce?)

Comment: @ДавидМанжула Да, оно)